# Pass Value to _process_registration_details()

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I changed in the processes of website_event_sale in Odoo v9.

```
    def registration_confirm(self, event, **post):
         order = request.website.sale_get_order(force_create=1)
         registrations = self._process_registration_details({'1-name' :"name", '1-email' :"email@email.com", '1-phone': "",'1-ticket_id':14})
         if order:
              order.write({'order_line': [(5, False, False)], 'is_adhesion': False})
         return super(website_event,self).registration_confirm(event, **post)
```

But I got :

```
    _process_registration_details
         counter, field_name = key.split('-', 1)
    ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

This is the original _process_regestration_details() :

```
      def _process_registration_details(self, details):
    ''' Process data posted from the attendee details form. '''
    registrations = {}
    global_values = {}
    for key, value in details.iteritems():
        counter, field_name = key.split('-', 1)
        if counter == '0':
            global_values[field_name] = value
        else:
            registrations.setdefault(counter, dict())[field_name] = value
    for key, value in global_values.iteritems():
        for registration in registrations.values():
            registration[key] = value
    return registrations.values()
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) split() is returning a list of strings. But you try to fill up to variables: counter, field_name.

Edit 1:

```py
split_key = key.split('-', 1)
counter = split_key[0]
field_name = split_key[1]
```

But i think that's not to best solution.

Comment: Is there a way to fill counter, field_name from the list? Or another way to fill the attributes ?